# windows libtool mingw looking in g drive

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, libtool

I'm cross compiling a program from ubuntu which has a makefile which uses libtool, g++, and SDL. When I run the makefile, it compiles all the object files, however when it gets to the link stage, it gives this error

```
g++.exe: error: g:mingw/3.4.5/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw/3.4.5/../../../dllcrt2.o
No such file or directory
```

This is the link command

```
libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++ -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_gfx -lm -rpath /usr/local/lib
-g -o libGameFrame.la Space2D/Space2D.lo Space2D/Point.lo Space2D/Vector.lo
Space2D/Velocity.lo GameControl/Events.lo GameControl/GameLoop.lo GameControl/App.lo
GameControl/DataManager.lo SurfaceX/SurfaceX.lo SurfaceX/SimpleSurf.lo 
SurfaceX/SafeSurf.lo SurfaceX/DoubleSurf.lo
```

My main wonder is what the G: drive is, and why it's looking there. Is there something to configure in libtool? or G++?

Comment: Add the linking command to your question. That error message also looks incomplete.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've made the edits